# TwinCat project in Visual Studio files show up with yellow triangle and examination mark

Tags: windows, visual-studio, plc, twincat, twincat-ads

My TwinCat PLC project has been going well.  Then one day it wouldn't run at all.  It turned out almost all files in the project have symbols of a yellow triangle with an exclamation mark on it.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved the problem by launching the Windows register editor as an admin, then go to
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SYSTEM -> CurrentControlSet -> Control -> Lsa -> fipsalgorithmpolicy. Find the Enabled field and modify its value to 0. Relaunch Visual Studio.

This solved the problem.  But the register gets re-enabled automatically all the time.  So it seems before launching Visual Studio, I have to disable this register again every time.

Comment: That sounds like a very complicated solution :p. The other day there was an issue with visual studio if you tried to [dock/split floating windows](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Unexpected-VS-crash-when-docking-or-spli/1323017). This was caused by a windows update and it was fixed in a VS update. Maybe this issue is also caused by a windows update? And perhaps in the mean time a visual studio update has been released which fixes this? Or else you could try to revert the windows update.